# microstack on ubuntu does not register cinder volume service

Tags: openstack, volume, cinder

mircostack installation failed to register cinder.

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Installation itself succeeded

```
root@ubuntu:~# snap install microstack --classic --edge
[...]
```

Initialization also succeeded with only a simple warning.

```
root@ubuntu:~# microstack.init --auto
2020-02-24 09:12:21,219 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring networking ...
2020-02-24 09:12:22,604 - microstack_init - INFO - Setting up ipv4 forwarding...
2020-02-24 09:12:23,904 - microstack_init - INFO - Opening horizon dashboard up to *
2020-02-24 09:12:25,047 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for RabbitMQ to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:5672
2020-02-24 09:12:25,072 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ started!
2020-02-24 09:12:25,072 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring RabbitMQ ...
2020-02-24 09:12:26,397 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ Configured!
2020-02-24 09:12:26,471 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for MySQL server to start ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:3306
2020-02-24 09:12:26,493 - microstack_init - INFO - Mysql server started! Creating databases ...
/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1287, 'Using GRANT for creating new user is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Create new user with CREATE USER statement.')
  result = self._query(query)
/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1287, "Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use ALTER USER statement for this operation.")
  result = self._query(query)
2020-02-24 09:12:28,039 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring Keystone Fernet Keys ...
2020-02-24 09:13:01,205 - microstack_init - INFO - Bootstrapping Keystone ...
2020-02-24 09:13:11,362 - microstack_init - INFO - Creating service project ...
2020-02-24 09:13:18,118 - microstack_init - INFO - Keystone configured!
2020-02-24 09:13:18,188 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring nova compute hypervisor ...
2020-02-24 09:13:34,039 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring nova control plane services ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:8774
2020-02-24 09:16:33,766 - microstack_init - INFO - Creating default flavors...
2020-02-24 09:17:05,828 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring Neutron
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:9696
2020-02-24 09:19:19,611 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring Glance ...
Waiting for 10.20.20.1:9292
2020-02-24 09:20:08,536 - microstack_init - INFO - Adding cirros image ...
2020-02-24 09:20:08,541 - microstack_init - INFO - Downloading cirros image ...
100% [........................................................................] 12716032 / 127160322020-02-24 09:20:18,112 - microstack_init - INFO - Creating microstack keypair (~/.ssh/id_microstack)
2020-02-24 09:20:21,411 - microstack_init - INFO - Creating security group rules ...
2020-02-24 09:20:33,853 - microstack_init - INFO - restarting libvirt and virtlogd ...
2020-02-24 09:20:34,136 - microstack_init - INFO - Complete. Marked microstack as initialized!
```

portal and command line are working

```
root@ubuntu:~# microstack.openstack image list
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name   | Status |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| fcb4efad-509f-4235-bd86-694125a0fbbc | cirros | active |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

It is failing to call colume command and in the portal (horizon) there is also no volume area visible.

```
root@ubuntu:~# microstack.openstack volume list
public endpoint for volumev2 service not found
```

In the service list I see, that cinder service is not registered.

```
root@ubuntu:~# microstack.openstack service list
+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID                               | Name      | Type      |
+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 237331a245714772a8d61eab3e6234e5 | keystone  | identity  |
| 69d4e94ceeba471baacddb9baf803a7a | neutron   | network   |
| 6c3a18bb84d3424e80178f4f40d4c861 | nova      | compute   |
| bba95e72a5b24ec989ec76d433577972 | glance    | image     |
| daa8cba4740643919b8474f188a7b3d4 | placement | placement |
+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I already installed it 3 times, all times with same result.

How can I further investigate or check what has failed or how can I fix it?

Regards
Lukas